# Unable to play Rubik's Cube game on Google Doodle in Chrome for Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, google

I'm unable to play **Rubik's Cube** game on **Google Doodle** in Chrome for Ubuntu.
It says I need the lastest version of Chrome to play, but I already updated everything and it still doesn't work. What could I do to play it?

Comment: I think that's not related to ubuntu in anyway. a bug created by google in its doogle, what does ubuntu has to do with this? and how can we fix this? i have chrome and just tried and it doesn't work, that's just how it is

Comment: chrome 34 here. works perfect :)

Comment: >Ask Ubuntu

Apparently asking Ubuntu really isn't such a good idea it seems?